# IBM ETL/DataStage CSV file missing final comma

Tags: csv, etl, datastage

My Team's using IBM's DataStage ETL tool to read a CSV file into a Salesforce instance. If the last column is blank the file doesn't have a second comma to close out the Record. That is, it's just ',' instead of ',,' at the end of a line. That's causing ETL to reject the file. Excel Anyone know if ETL can be configured to handle the missing record deliminator? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can count the commas in every line and for the line if the final comma is missing add accordingly. All this you need to implement in sequncer command stage.